# Stretch and start FlatButton.icon

Tags: flutter

In a `Column` there's a group of `FlatButton`s created with `FlatButton.icon()`
so that it has image and text laid beside each other, 
I need the `FlatButton`'s contents to be aligned to the left, but the button is stretched horizontally,

setting the column's `crossAxisAlignment` to `CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` stretches the button's width as I want, but centers the button's content:

[image]

and setting it to `CrossAxisAlignment.start` aligns the button's contents to the left but the button's width gets shrinked:

[image]

is it possible to align the button contents to the left but the button be stretched? or I have to use other combinations of widgets (`InkWell` for example?)

Comment: take a look at [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.htmll)

Comment: @hiwajalal I tried `Align` already but didn't work, I think it's not an alignment issue more than how the `FlatButton` is rendered

Comment: it seems your button is felling the full screen so why not use `CrossAxisAlignment.start` and set the width of your button to infinity by assigning `double.infinity` to it's width.

Comment: If you mean wrapping it with a `SizedBox` (cause `FlatButton` doesn't have a `width` property), it doesn't work either => has the same effect as `CrossAxisAlignment.stretch`

Comment: please check my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a normal `FlatButton()` constructor that has the child property and then you can have a row as the child and make it's `mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.start` and make your text and icon it's children's, like below:

```
Scaffold(
          body: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                color: Colors.grey,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(Icons.check),
                    SizedBox(width: 10),
                    Text('Recharge and balance')
                  ],
                ), onPressed: () {},
              )
            ],
          ),
        )
```

the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit of a hack, but you could use a regular FlatButton widget and do something like this could work:

```
class SampleWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            maxWidth: 200,
          ),
          child: FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.home),
                Text('Recharge and balance'),
                Spacer(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Spacer widget will take up the remaining space of row. All you have to do from here is just adjust the padding of the Icon to be the same as FlatButton.icon

Comment: error: 
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#27293 relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1687 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was
    _FlatButtonWithIcon

Answer (score 0):

Try changing padding property of `Flatbutton` to  `Edgeinsets.only(left: 0.0)`

```
padding: Edgeinsets.only(left: 0.0),
```